# How do I do a SQL Group By with an aggregate?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a pair of linked tables, the first with job information and the second with material information (each job has 1-10 materials). I am also joining a couple other tables (with customer info and additional job info). I want a total sum of all material of the same type within the same job. Thus job 78100 has three entries of the same material with quantities of 800, 800, and 900. I want the final table to say "78100, etc. . . 2500."

I get the results I want with the following code but I also need the material name, which is in another table that is joined only to CJF.

```
SELECT
    OJ.JobN, C.CustomerName, OJ.JobDescription, OJ.Quantity, 
    OJ.JobCloseDate, CJ.FSC, 
    (SELECT SUM(CJF.MT_NETSHEETS)
     FROM CT_JobForm CJF
     WHERE CJF.JobN = OJ.JobN)
FROM 
    OpenJob OJ 
JOIN 
    Customer C ON OJ.CustomerN = C.CustomerN
JOIN 
    CT_Job2 CJ ON OJ.JobN = CJ.JobN
WHERE 
    JobDescription LIKE '%FSC%'
    AND JobCloseDate BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '12-31-2016'
ORDER BY 
    OJ.JobN ASC
```

I can get the material name using this code, but doing so causes be to lose the grouping (the new code is inside the double-asterisks).

```
SELECT 
    OJ.JobN, C.CustomerName, OJ.JobDescription, OJ.Quantity, 
    OJ.JobCloseDate, CJ.FSC, 
    (SELECT SUM(CJF.MT_NETSHEETS)
     FROM CT_JobForm CJF
     WHERE CJF.JobN = OJ.JobN),
    **(SELECT MCC.MCCDescription
     FROM MatlCostCntr MCC
     WHERE CJF.MCCN = MCC.MCCN)**
FROM 
    OpenJob OJ 
JOIN 
    Customer C ON OJ.CustomerN = C.CustomerN
JOIN 
    CT_Job2 CJ ON OJ.JobN = CJ.JobN
**JOIN 
    CT_JobForm CJF ON CJF.JobN = OJ.JobN**
WHERE 
    JobDescription LIKE '%FSC%'
    AND JobCloseDate BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '12-31-2016'
ORDER BY 
    OJ.JobN ASC
```

I tried nesting the MCCN Select statement in the Netsheet one but couldn't make that work at all. Is there a way to do this that isn't more work than just manually fixing it in Excel?

Comment: And if there is more than on `MCCN` per `JobN`, then what do you want?

Comment: I'd like to sum them by MCCN. The current numbers I'm working with all have the same MCCN, but it could be different. What I'm supposed to provide is SUM(Netsheets) per MCCN per Job.